Background Color Issue with Scaffold in Flutter, Hiding Tab views - Extra Black Space at Top
Black space at the top. I'm working on an intro page for my Flutter app using the Scaffold widget and I wanted to hide the tab views, but I'm encountering an issue with the background color not covering the entire screen. Despite setting the backgroundColor for the Scaffold, I still see unwanted black space at the top of the screen.
I have tired
 void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, 
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent, 
  ));...


try to change statusBarColor: Colors.transparent to the same color as your Scaffold background color.

You should wrap the Scaffold in a SafeArea, and then wrap the SafeArea in a Container with the desired background color. This approach should help ensure the correct color is applied across the screen.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: IntroPage(),
    );
  }
}

class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue, // Set your desired background color here
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // Make Scaffold background transparent
          body: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Welcome!',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

